# How to make xampp work online

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, xampp

I have installed xampp and created a website, I want to access it online and I can not do that..
What I've done:

1. I have a static IP from my ISP
2. I have static IP so on my pc's IP address is  always is 192.168.15.102
3. I've done port forwarding : port 80 on tcp in my router from external to 192.168.15.102:80

and it does not work with my real IP. It works locally so if I access from my laptop with 192.168.15.102 it works but if I access from my real IP it does not?
I've tried like ex. 12.34.548:80, nothing. Tried to change ports on Apache to 8012 and to router too for forwarding to the same port, again just works from my router IP and not from my real IP (tried like : 12.34.548:8012 and 12.34.548) but nothing..

Comment: Try if you can reach your site from a proxy site, because sometimes you can't access your public ip from your internal network. If you can't reach it from a proxy site, the port forwarding isn't working.

Comment: Yea, I tried from website and it says that port is closed, I made factory reset to my router and open ports again but no port is open again..
Does router have any firewall or something ?

Comment: Yes most routers have a firewall but when you forward the port(s) it doesn't affect them. Which modem and router do you have? Sometimes you have to forward them in the modem too.

Comment: Tenda Wireless N High Power Router 300Mbps FH302D w/2 with Detachable Antennas

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Tenda/FH303/

Comment: On which IP is xampp listening? E.g is it only bound to ::1 and 127.1 ?

Answer (score -2):

For going online with your website you need public ip for your website. For that you need to register the domain. Local ip can be used to browse the website you have on locally connected system.

check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Publishing_your_website)